# HAProxy how to "stick-table" ip connection to same backend?

Tags: frontend, backend, haproxy

My HAProxy config:

```
global
maxconn 300000

defaults
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option  http-server-close
  option  dontlognull
  option  redispatch
  option  contstats
  retries 3
  backlog 10000
  timeout client            5s
  timeout connect           5s
  timeout server            5s
  timeout tunnel            120s
  timeout http-keep-alive   5s
  timeout http-request      15s
  default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
  option forwardfor

frontend ft_web
  bind *:8000 name http
  maxconn 300000
  stick-table type ip size 5000k expire 5m store conn_cur
  tcp-request connection reject if { src_conn_cur ge 3 }
  tcp-request connection track-sc1 src   
  default_backend bk_web

backend bk_web
   balance roundrobin

server s8001 127.0.0.1:8001 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8001 check
server s8002 127.0.0.1:8002 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8002 check
server s8003 127.0.0.1:8003 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8003 check
server s8004 127.0.0.1:8004 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8004 check
```

**Currently if someone is openning more then 3 connections, all other are droped, but I need to stick IP to backend so every time someone with same IP access frontend he goes to same backend node ...**

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing the stick on and stick match parts.  My config would look like this:

```
global
maxconn 300000

defaults
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option  http-server-close
  option  dontlognull
  option  redispatch
  option  contstats
  retries 3
  backlog 10000
  timeout client            5s
  timeout connect           5s
  timeout server            5s
  timeout tunnel            120s
  timeout http-keep-alive   5s
  timeout http-request      15s
  default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
  option forwardfor

frontend ft_web
  bind *:8000 name http
  maxconn 300000
  stick-table type ip size 5000k expire 5m store conn_cur
  stick on src table bk_web
  tcp-request connection reject if { src_conn_cur ge 3 }
  tcp-request connection track-sc1 src   
  default_backend bk_web

backend bk_web
   balance roundrobin

stick match src table bk_web
server s8001 127.0.0.1:8001 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8001 check
server s8002 127.0.0.1:8002 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8002 check
server s8003 127.0.0.1:8003 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8003 check
server s8004 127.0.0.1:8004 maxconn 500 weight 10 cookie s8004 check
```

Comment: OK, but if there is "nbproc 8" will it stick all to one table or for every process separate ???

Comment: I believe this post answers your question, basically it says No it's not shared.
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/4585
That said, Haproxy 1.5 in development now will have shared stick-table between separate instances

Comment: Sorry, I get error with this config "Proxy 'bk_web': stick-table 'bk_web' used but not configured."